# Binding Hyperlink inside Paragraph to a Command (MVVM)

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, command, uwp

I have a Hyperlink inside a `RichTextBlock`. I'm using MVVM and I would like to bind it to a `Command`. How do I do it?

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="This is " />
        <Hyperlink>
            <Hyperlink.Inlines>
                <Run Text="a link" />
            </Hyperlink.Inlines>
        </Hyperlink>
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

Comment: Try `<Hyperlink Command="{Binding MyCommand}">`

Comment: Seems like *Hyperlink* doesn't have command property - you will have to create your own extended class or maybe simpler just use new `x:Bind` for *Click* event, hence it can bind methods from the behind.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I don't think the `Command` property is available on hyperlinks in UWP.

Comment: @MikeEason Right, my bad, I missed the 'uwp' tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add do this using the `InlineUIContainer` and then adding an `HyperlinkButton`.

```
<RichTextBlock>
    <Paragraph>
        <Run Text="This is" />
        <InlineUIContainer >
            <HyperlinkButton Margin="0,0,0,-10" 
                             Command="{Binding LinkCommand}">
                a link
            </HyperlinkButton>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run Text="and this is some additional text" />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBlock>
```

You can also use a binding for the link text:

```
<HyperlinkButton Margin="0,0,0,-10" 
                 Command="{Binding myCommand}"
                 Content="{Binding LinkText}">
</HyperlinkButton>
```

I have used the negative margin to align the link with the other text content.